# VUE's focus() method return a console error? How to use it correctly?

Tags: vue.js, select, input, focus

I'm trying to focus on several elements of my form but the first one, despite being applied, returns an error by console.
This is my template:

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="row">
        <h1 class="animal-title">Your selection is : </h1>
      </div>

      <div class="wrapper">
        <form class="first-form" @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
          <div class="image-wrapper">
            <div class="sel-image">
              <div v-on:click="imageSelected = true" v-for="item in items" v-bind:key="item.id">
                <label>
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="selectedItem"
                    ref="item"
                    :value="item.id"
                    v-model="itemFormInfo.selectedItem"
                    @change="onChangeItem($event)"
                  />
                  <img v-if="item.id === 1" src="../../assets/1.png" />
                  <img v-if="item.id === 2" src="../../assets/2.png" />
                  <img v-if="item.id === 3" src="../../assets/3.png" />
                </label>
                <p class="cie-animal-subtitle">{{item.name}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-select">
            <div v-show="filteredStock && (imageSelected || itemFormInfo.selectedItem) > 0">
              <h1 v-if="this.itemName === 'Phone' || this.itemName === 'Tablet'" for="selectedItem" ref="itemVisible">
                Select the brand of your <span>{{this.itemName}}</span> :
              </h1>
              <h1 v-if="this.itemName === 'PC'" for="selectedBreed" ref="itemVisible">
                Select the type of your <span>{{this.itemName}}</span> :
              </h1>
              <select
                ref="brand"
                class="form-control"
                id="selectedBrand"
                v-model="itemFormInfo.selectedBrand"
                @change="onChangeBrand($event)">
                <option v-for="brand in filteredBrand" v-bind:key="brand.name">{{ brand.name }}</option>
              </select>
              <div v-show="this.isBrandSelected">
                <h1>What are you going to use your 
                  <span>{{itemName}}</span> for ?
                </h1>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  id="componentName"
                  ref="componentName"
                  class="form-control fields"
                  style="text-transform: capitalize"
                  v-model="itemFormInfo.component"
                  @keypress="formChange($event)"
                />
                <div class="loader-spinner" v-if="loading">
                  <app-loader/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="service-options" v-show="isComponentCompleted">
            <div class="from-group">
              <h1>
                Here are the options for your <span>{{this.itemFormInfo.component}}</span> :
              </h1>
              <div class="services">
                <div class="column-service" v-for="option in options" v-bind:key="option.name">
                  <div class="service-name">{{option.name}}</div>
                  <div class="service-price">{{option.price.toString().replace(".", ",")}} </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

and here my first method

```js
    onChangeItem(event) {
      let item = event.target._value;
      this.itemName = this.getItemName(item);      
      if (this.isItemSelected = true) {
        this.isItemSelected = false;
        this.isComponentCompleted = false;
        this.isLoaderFinished = false;
        this.itemFormInfo.name = ""
      }
    this.$refs.item.focus();
    },
```

in this function that I control my first input, the focus is working but it returns me by console the following error:

> "this.$refs.item.focus is not a function at VueComponent.onChangeItem"

I have seen some references to similar cases where they involved the reference in a **setTimeout** or used the **this.$nextTick(() =>** method but it didn't work in my case.

What am I doing wrong?
How can I focus on the next select with ref brand, once I have chosen the value of the first input?

Thank you all for your time and help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*How can I focus on the next select with ref brand, once I have chosen the value of the first input?*

You want to put focus on `brand` but your `onChangeItem` handler is calling `this.$refs.item.focus()` (trying to focus `item`). Seems strange to me...

Reason for the error is you are using `ref` inside `v-for`.
[Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref): *When used on elements/components with v-for, the registered reference will be an Array containing DOM nodes or component instances*

So the correct way for accessing `item` `ref` will be `this.$refs.item[index].focus()`.

Just be aware that right now [v-for refs do not guarantee the same order as your source Array](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4952#issuecomment-280661367) - you can find some workarounds in the issue discussion...

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly.
As for wanting to make a reference in brand, I still didn't have it implemented and since the first one was failing me, I didn't know where to go from here.